# How to add a song in Zune hub to "now playing"

Tags: windows-phone-7

In music hub there is a function call "add to now playing" when you press and hold on a song title.

I want to do something similar to this to add a song from a list to now playing list.

How can I do this by code? I couldn't find any method from SongCollection and MediaPlayer in Windows Phone 7.

The example from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx only show how to add the song to the historyItem in Zune Hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't do this from your application. You can only use MediaPlayer to play a selected song, but not to queue it.

What you can do thou, is to call `MediaPlayer.Play` passing a custom `SongCollection` as a parameter, and then use `.MoveNext` and `.MovePreviouse`to navigate to a next or prev. records respectively.

Comment: Thanks you for the info, the reason I want to to this is to create a playlist in my app, this is new feature in Mango release.

Comment: Hmm, I was unaware that there will be such functionality in Mango. I am sure that I have reviewed the mango Music and Video hub integration docs on msdn, and there were nothing mentioning this.